# Что выбрать for или while?

Tags: python, циклы, for, while

Больше теоритический вопрос выбора.

На мой субъективный взляд и я указывал на это в нескольких ответах на SO, я почти всегда искользую `for`. И только где необходим бесконечный цикл (например слушать входящие сообщения) я использую `while`.

Есть ли конкретные правила где и почему надо использовать ту или иную конструкцию?

Comment: Нормально изложено https://stackoverflow.com/a/920692/15035314

Comment: Для каждой конкретной задачи нужно выбирать то что вам подходит лучше всего в данный момент. Считаю что вопрос нужно закрыть не по причине "слишком простой" а по причине "нельзя дать однозначный ответ", т.к. сейчас ответ на данный вопрос будет пересказыванием главы учебника про циклы.

Comment: ассоциация https://stackoverflow.com/q/920645/10562663

Comment: @Dmitry простите, а если у "них" станет модно прыгать с моста, вы предлагаете и нам начать повторять? Не вижу засилья таких вопросов на ruSO, как и не вижу необходимости разжевывать то что есть в каждом учебнике. Ответ в пять строк не даст понимания когда конкретно это использовать в граничных случаях, и может в таковых быть даже вредным, считаю что данный вопрос имеет право на существование только если автор вопроса сделает подробную выдержку в виде ответа, о которой вы говорите, иначе это скатится к пересказу документации.

Comment: Вопрос хоть и простой, но все же ответы на него тут будут много кому полезны.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В принципе, на английском SO нормально написано. Но даже не заглядывая туда я был готов дать такой же ответ по сути.

`for` - для перебора элементов такой сущности, по которой можно итерироваться: коллекция, генератор, итератор.

`while` - для бесконечного цикла, а также для циклов, где нет последовательного перебора сущностей, а есть некое условие окончания цикла, либо вычисляемое, либо зависящее от ввода пользователя или какого-то другого недетерминированного события.

Большинство циклов в питоне всё же сводится к `for`, потому что обычно требуется именно что-то перебрать, какую-то коллекцию: список объектов, диапазон чисел, строки файла, выборку из базы данных.

Да, `while` при желании тоже можно использовать для перебора сущностей, но это будет: более длинно, менее красиво и менее понятно. И наоборот, превратить `while` в `for` теоретически тоже можно, но это будет ещё более сложно, непонятно и бессмысленно.

Answer (score 3):

Хочу дополнить иформацию, основываясь на документации

#### While

Выдержка из [документации](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-while-statement)

> The while statement is used for repeated execution as long as an expression is true
> **Перевод**
> Оператор *while* используется для повторного выполнения, так долго, пока выражение истинно.

#### For

Выдержка из [документации](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-for-statement)

> The for statement is used to iterate over the elements of a sequence (such as a string, tuple or list) or other iterable object
> **Перевод**
> Оператор *for* используется для перебора элементов последовательности (таких как  строка, кортеж или список) или другого итерируемого объекта

#### Резюме

Другими словами, если решается тривиальная задача, выбор прост -> есть итерируемый объект (включая генераторы) используй **for**, в остальных случаях - **while**.

#### Оговоримся?

Как было указано в комментарии к самому вопросу от @ВладимирКлыков

> Для каждой конкретной задачи нужно выбирать то что вам подходит лучше всего в данный момент.

Соглашусь и добавлю, что к выбору той или иной конструкции надо подходить либо со знанием дела, либо с холодной головой и использовать опыт и рекомендации документации.

Answer (score 2):

Дополню в том что while также нужен для ожидания какого-то события.

```
ynq = ""
while ynq not in ['y','n']:
    ynq = input('введите y или n')
```

Answer (score -6):

Нет никакой разницы. С помощью for тоже можно сделать бесконечный цикл 'for (int i = 1; i >= 0; i = 1 - i)' - это просто иллюстрация на условном ЯП. В цикле while можно использовать счётчик. Так что делайте цикл как вам угодно и не мучайтесь. Разницы в во времени тоже быть не должно (можно проверить при желании).

И так, сутки прошли. Публикую, как можно в Питоне с помощью команды for сделать бесконечный цикл, который выдаёт ноль и один по очереди:

```
class FlipFlop:
  def __init__(s):
    s.d=0;
  def __iter__(s):
    return s
  def __next__(s):
    s.d=1-s.d
    return s.d
for i in FlipFlop():
  print(i)
```

Таким образом можно сделать всё, что угодно. Зависит только от реализации итератора в коллекции.

Для новичков, как хотел автор вопроса, добавляю, что команда for перебирает коллекцию не абы как, а так, как это запрограммировано в её итераторе. И это можно изменить, реализовав таким образом нужную функциональность.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139992/discussion-on-answer-by-rotabor---for--while).